# ListView with ViewPagers

Tags: android, android-listview, swipe, android-viewpager

Im having trouble with my UI. 
It contains a ListView , with ViewPagers as List Items.
The problem is that the horizontal scrolls seem to get interrupted by the ListView (catching vertical scrolls).
What i want to achieve is that no matter what happens, the horizontal scrolls finish all the time. Right now they stop half way sometime.

this is probably a common problem, but i havent found a solution yet. 
I've tried to intercept horizontal scrolls on the the listview, but although I can intercept, it still causes the swipe to stop.

can anyone point me in the right direction ?

Comment: by swipeview you mean ViewPager?

Answer (score 0):

ViewPagers are not compatible with ListViews.
Sorry.
[ViewPager inside ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674529/viewpager-inside-listview)

Comment: boo, I'm not saying that it's smart but but off course you can do it. Think about the slop and the intercept touch. Check out this video to start to get an idea https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NYtB6mlu7vA