# ViewPager inside ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-viewpager

Is there a way to add a viewpager as a listview item?

I want to add it as a "header" on top of my listview before all real list items follow. I tried using addHeaderView() or declaring multiple view types in my list adapter, however, the viewpager never shows up whatever way I try.

Has anyone done something similar? Help!

Comment: Would have been good to include your original layout code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting [Dianne Hackborn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8164485/viewpager-and-onitemclicklistener-in-listview/8548580#8548580), `ViewPager` is "just not intended to be used as an item in a list"

Comment: I read that, but I found out that ViewPager does not support wrap_content and thats why it does not show up. If I explicitly set width/height in the layout params then it works. I don't want every item in the list to be a viewpager, just the top "header" one as I use it for a "gallery" type of view for promoted items.

Comment: @dnkoutso: Ms. Hackborn is one of Android's core engineers. She might have even written `ViewPager`. I humbly suggest that you find some other solution. For example, you might use `Gallery` for a gallery. Or use `HorizontalScrollView`. Putting scrollable things in scrollable things has historically been troublesome, but if a Googler steers you away from a solution, you would be well advised to honor the suggestion.

Comment: Gallery is a very old widget not suitable for my needs. At the moment I use a ViewFlipper which does the job well but I would prefer the smoothness and functionality of a ViewPager. I understand the concern of blending the two, but I dont see a problem with it as long as I specify the dimensions I want the viewpager to be. p.s I know who Dianne is :)

Comment: hi is it possible to add view pagger in header , is there any example, Ive tried wont display anything, any examples.

Comment: Not sure why this is the accepted answer. This is commentary and doesn't answer the asker's question.

Comment: http://dallasgutauckis.com/2013/04/30/android-putting-a-viewpager-inside-a-listview/

Comment: @CommonsWare I want to make a image slider (carousel) inside a recyclerview. Can I use viewPager. If not, then how can I make the clid imageViews of HorizontalScrollView to match parent (only one image on screen at a time). android:fillViewport="true" only works for one child view.

Comment: @FarooqKhan: A more typical approach here would be nested `RecyclerViews`. If you wanted a `ViewPager` with views for the pages, that might work. I would be *very* hesitant to use a `ViewPager` with fragments for the pages. I would not use `HorizontalScrollView` for your use case.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for your response. I am also using HorizontalScrollView but how can I make the width of all child views to match_parent. As doing android:fillViewport="true" only works if LinearLayout inside HorizontalScrollView has only one child.

Answer (score 12):

Do not use `wrap_content`, try to calculate and set ViewPager size programmatically and then add ViewPager as a header of ListView.

Comment: this gives poor results too

Comment: Yes this way it works. I don't know why it didn't work for @RafaelSanches