# Android - Create a Vertical ListView with Horizontal scrollable row

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager, horizontal-scrolling

I need a Vertical ListView where each row is a horizontal scrollable list of items.
Each items is an image with a button.
I need the app to be compatible with Android 2.2.

I've read 3 working solutions here

1. Use a custom Horizontal ListView as rows
2. Use a ViewPager as rows
   [ViewPager inside ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674529/viewpager-inside-listview)
3. Use an horizontal ScrollView

These solutions are a bit old and each has their detractors.

So I was wondering, at the current state, is there an "official" solution for my problem?
Or, what is the best one?

Comment: just out of curiosity, why do you need such type of view?

Comment: It's a request from a customer. They have this kind of view on the iOS version of their app and wants to replicate this behaviour in android.

Comment: You have read 3 working solution..But still you have query. There is no such kind of view. If you get cook book solution, i guarantee, your touch event will clash, and it will not work smooth

Comment: android has said in its developer's site that it is not advisable to use `Scrollable` view within other `Scrollable` view.

Comment: Ok, i've managed to do the task using a listview and horizontallistview as rows.
Using some trick the scroll part works really smooth. I've used a lazyloader for the image and it seems to work fine too. Now i have to understand how to save the position of the rows once you scroll away and then you scroll back to a previous row.

Comment: add itemId to your listitem Model class and depending on the value of itemId you can get to know in which row are.

Comment: the problem was that the setSelection was not implemented in the horizontalListView.

Comment: @Torsen I have the  same problem as yours. Can you please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

If the no of items in the vertical ListView are fixed then you are better off using Horizontal ListViews for each.

Comment: No item is fixed. They are loaded from a WS.