# Lazy loading ViewPagers in a ScrollView

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager, scrollview, lazy-loading

Im trying to inflate multiple `ViewPagers` into a `ScrollView` where each `ViewPager` is using a FragmentStatePagerAdapter.

The `ViewPager` consist of fragments with three `ImageViews` for each page.

Im using UniversalImageLoader for the async loading of the images but I cant get a lazy load to work.

The problem is when my app is inflating lets say 10 `ViewPagers` with 3 `ImageViews` for each `TripplePosterFragment1`, and another 10 `ViewPagers` with 3 `ImageViews` for `TripplePosterFragment2` since the `mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1)` kicks in.

Its a total of 60 async requests firing during my `progressLayout` is visible.

My `MainFragment` with following method:

```
private void renderSubCarousels(ArrayList<Carousel> carousels) {

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    int i = 1;

    LinearLayout subCarouselLayout = (LinearLayout) mScrollView.findViewById(R.id.index_subcategory_carousel_container);

    for (final Carousel carousel : carousels) {

        RelativeLayout carouselWrapper = (RelativeLayout) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.main_pager_layout, null);
        LinearLayout mContainer = (LinearLayout) carouselWrapper.findViewById(R.id.main_pager_container);
        mContainer.setId(Constants.BASEID_LINEARLAYOUT + i);

        ViewPager mPager = (ViewPager) mContainer.findViewById(R.id.main_pager);   
        mPager.setId(Constants.BASEID_VIEWPAGER + i);
        mPager.setAdapter(new PagerPosterAdapter(getFragmentManager(),Constants.TRIPLE_POSTERS, carousel));
        subCarouselLayout.addView(carouselWrapper);
        i++;
    }
    progressLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

My `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`:

```
public class PagerPosterAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private int mPageSize;
    private Carousel mCarousel;

    public PagerPosterAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int pageSize, Carousel carousel) {
        super(fm);
        this.mPageSize = pageSize;
        this.mCarousel = carousel;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        int maxPageIndex = (int) Math.ceil((float) mCarousel.getAssets().size() / mPageSize);     
        return maxPageIndex;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        ArrayList<Asset> assets = mCarousel.getAssets();
        int from = position*mPageSize;
        int to = (position+1)*(mPageSize);
        if(to > assets.size()-1)
            to = assets.size();

        return (TripplePosterFragment.newInstance(assets.subList(from,  to)));
    }
}
```

The `TripplePosterFragment` where the ImageView rendering happens:

```
private void initViews() {

    ImageView mFirstImageView = (ImageView) mLinearLayout.findViewById(R.id.first_pager_poster);        
    ImageView mSecondImageView = (ImageView)mLinearLayout.findViewById(R.id.second_pager_poster);
    ImageView mThirdImageView = (ImageView)mLinearLayout.findViewById(R.id.third_pager_poster);

    for(int i = 0;i < assets.size(); i++){

        ImageView image = null;

        switch(i){
        case 0:
            image = (ImageView) mLinearLayout.findViewById(R.id.first_pager_poster);
            break;      
        case 1:
            image = (ImageView) mLinearLayout.findViewById(R.id.second_pager_poster);
                break;
        case 2:
            image = (ImageView) mLinearLayout.findViewById(R.id.third_pager_poster);
            break;
        default:
            continue;   
        }

        //The ScrollView in MainFragment

        CustomScrollView mParentScrollView = (CustomScrollView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.index_scrollviewparent);

        Rect scrollBounds = new Rect();
        mParentScrollView.getHitRect(scrollBounds);
        if (image.getLocalVisibleRect(scrollBounds)) {
            // Any portion of the imageView, even a single pixel, is within the visible window
            ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(assets.get(i).getPoster(), image);
            System.out.println("Im within");
        else {
            // NONE of the imageView is within the visible window
            System.out.println("Im NOT within");
        }
    }
}
```

I need to check if the images are visible and load them when they are. But `System.out.println("Im NOT within");` is spammed in the `Log`. Im sure there is a way of doing it similar to this, but I need some help.

I've tried a quick approach of doing much of the meat inside a ListView but its not optimal, at least after some reading, [ViewPager inside ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674529/viewpager-inside-listview)

**UPDATE**

Same core issue as before, but using a new approach HorizontalListViews instad of Pagers.

`ListViews` seems like the way to go. By using `ArrayAdapter` to populate a regular vertical `ListView` with multiple `HListViews` lazy loads the images vertically for each new row, and horizontally for each image inside, as intended.

**Problem:**  Horizontal positions are lost. The `horizontalAdapter` is inherited from a recycled view onto next list item. This *positions* the new list item to where the recycled list item was.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    View view = convertView;

    if (view == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.carousel_frame_layout, null);
        holder.carouselList = (HListView) view.findViewById(R.id.hListView);
        view.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }
    Carousel mCarousel = mData.get(position);

    // Problem: Re-uses adapters from convertview
    if (holder.carouselList.getAdapter() == null) {
        SubCategoryCarouselAdapter horizontalAdapter = new SubCategoryCarouselAdapter(mContext, mCarousel.getAssets());
        holder.carouselList.setAdapter(horizontalAdapter);
    } else {
        ((SubCategoryCarouselAdapter) holder.carouselList.getAdapter()).update(mCarousel.getAssets());
    }

    return view;
}
```

The solution could be to save the inner `horizontalAdapter` to a designated list item position, but I dont know how to do this when the `HListView` itself is recycled.

**UPDATE 3**

Found a working solution for `HListViews`. But I have still to test if this is working for `ViewPagers`.

Its lazy loading images both horizontally and vertically when using `addHeaderView` on parent `ListView` for each inner `HListView`. I´ve used [HorizontalVariableListView](https://github.com/sephiroth74/HorizontalVariableListView) together with [UniversalImageLoader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) for the carousels.

```
LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService
            (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

for (final Carousel carousel : carousels) {
    View carouselWrapper = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.carousel_sub_category_layout, null);
    listView.addHeaderView(carouselWrapper);
    listView.setAdapter(null);

    HListView horizontalList = (HListView) carouselWrapper.findViewById(R.id.hListView);
    SubCategoryCarouselAdapter mAdapter = new SubCategoryCarouselAdapter(getActivity(), carousel.getAssets());
    horizontalList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use a ListView instead of ScrollView? It has a function of recycling views, so loading will start only for those pagers which are visible on screen right now. Otherwise you should subclass your ScrollView in order to check if Pager is visible right now

Comment: Yes, seems like it´s the way to go. I cant get the recycling of view and adapters to work. 

I've moved away from pagers and using HorizontalListViews instead. But it has the same behaviour by loading all images when inside a ScrollView.

As you said, the HorizontalListViews are recycled, but so are the adapters tied to each recycled view. Updated my answer!

Comment: I may suggest two following solutions: 
1) save your adapters in the List and get the needed adapter by its position (actually I don't think that it's a good idea since it's not effective in terms of memory)
2) add a pointer to your Carousel (I assume it has the list of data to be displayed) class which will point to the active position and then modify SubCategoryCarouselAdapter constructor in order to get this pointer and set the corresponding position (I think that this way is way better than the first one, as for the pointer it can be just an int value indicating the number of the page)

Comment: At least this should work in case your HListView is paginated as the ViewPager

Comment: The 2) solution will most likely be best when using Pagers. But Im not sure about reusing adapters for recycled views, then updating the position with the saved pointer. I assume its how you suggested? 

I've updated my question again, with a different approach. This will actually lazy load images both horizontally and vertically. The fragment holding this loads quickly as well. I dont know if this has a bad impact over all, but I cannot find a better solution for this approach.

Answer (score 2):

Could you set a breakpoint at

```
if (image.getLocalVisibleRect(scrollBounds)) {
```

and see what properties (width/height/position) image and scrollBounds have?

Also, when is

```
private void initViews() {
```

called?