# Achieve ViewPager like effect for each row in a listview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-viewpager, swipe-gesture

I have an ListView activity where I have row of elements, & I need to achieve ViewPager like effect on swiping right or left.

I have heard that ViewPager cannot be used as rows inside a listview 
Source: [ViewPager inside ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674529/viewpager-inside-listview)

So, how do I implement Viewpager like effects on swiping right or left on a row item in listview?

One hack I found was provided by Dallas Gutauckis
Link: http://dallasgutauckis.com/2013/04/30/android-putting-a-viewpager-inside-a-listview/

Comment: [Listview Android swipe](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=listview%20android%20swipe) for your reference.

Comment: @Gunaseelan The effect provided in your reference is swipe to dismiss.

I need viewpager like effects on swiping.

Comment: Update : This can be solved using a recyclerview