# ViewPager width fill_parent does not work

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager

I have a fragment with listview ,its adapter hold 2 types of cells (depending on position).

- First cell in list should be custom view which holds ( Button, ViewPager, CirclePageIndicator ),first cell width is match_parent
- Second cell is also custom view which hold buttons and image view.

My problem is i can not see the view pager in first cell when i put ViewPager.width to wrap_content or fill_parent or match_parent (view pager does not appear) ,however if i put a width for example 300dp ,i get to see the ViewPager

I can see the button and CirclePageIndicator which is set in same first cell with ViewPager

---

If you need more information please let me know ,any hint will be appreciate it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the problem ,it seems ViewPager is not really compatible with listView [ListView with ViewPagers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927795/listview-with-viewpagers)

Also ViewPager does not work right with wrap_content,so it seems i will change the whole view